# Spring Data JDBC MappedCollection casing issues with Postgres + Oracle

Tags: spring, postgresql, oracle, spring-data-jdbc

This is my current repo structure, I'm looking for a solution that works with both Postgres and OracleDB and preferably does not involve changing my DB schema to accomodate the ORM. Whether Postgres or Oracle is used is in defined in the `spring.datasource.url` in the `application.properties` file.

```
data class NewsCover(
    @Id val tenantId: TenantId,
    val openOnStart: Boolean,
    val cycleDelay: Int,

    @MappedCollection(idColumn = "tenant_id", keyColumn = "tenant_id")
    val sections: Set<NewsCoverSection>,
)

data class NewsCoverSection(
    @Id val id: NewsCoverSectionId,
    val title: String,
    val pinnedOnly: Boolean,
    val position: Int,
    val tenantId: TenantId,
    ... some other fields ...
)

interface NewsCoverRepo : CrudRepository<NewsCover, TenantId> { ... }
```

This works just fine with Postgresql, but creates errors when uses with Oracle:

```
SELECT "NEWS_COVER_SECTION"."ID" AS "ID", "NEWS_COVER_SECTION"."TITLE" AS "TITLE", "NEWS_COVER_SECTION"."POSITION" AS "POSITION", "NEWS_COVER_SECTION"."TENANT_ID" AS "TENANT_ID", "NEWS_COVER_SECTION"."PINNED_ONLY" AS "PINNED_ONLY" 
FROM "NEWS_COVER_SECTION" 
WHERE "NEWS_COVER_SECTION"."tenant_id" = ?
```

See the quoted idColumn/keyColumn names in the @MappedCollection. They are lower case. That is fine for Postgres, but does not work with Oracle. Changing `tenant_id` to `TENANT_ID` fixes the problem for Oracle, but breaks Postgres.

**What I tried:**

1. A [NamingStrategy](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jdbc/docs/current/reference/html/#jdbc.entity-persistence.naming-strategy) override for Oracle, but I can't seem to override those quoted identifiers.
2. Conditional column names in @MappedCollection, but @MappedCollection only accepts compile time constants and does not support SpEL, so I can't differentiate based on the `spring.datasource.url` property.

Any ideas how I can get it to query for `"news_cover_section"."tenant_id"` when the DB is Postgres and `"NEWS_COVER_SECTION"."TENANT_ID"` when the DB is Oracle?

Comment: The all uppercase query should work just fine in Oracle.

Comment: My problem is getting it to work with either Postgres and Oracle, depending on which DB is configured as datasource. I have quoted column identifiers in the @MappedCollection annotation.
`@MappedCollection(idColumn = "tenant_id", keyColumn = "tenant_id")` works with Postgres, `@MappedCollection(idColumn = "TENANT_ID", keyColumn = "TENANT_ID")` works with Oracle. But neither works with both DBs.

Comment: You should tell your obfuscation layer to **never** quote any identifier.

Comment: Thank you, that seems to be the easiest solution for now. Disabling forceQuote created a couple of small issues in other places, but those were easily manageable.

Answer (score 0):

As you found out you can disable the behaviour of quoting all names by setting the [`forceQuote` property of the `JdbcMappingContext`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jdbc/docs/current/api//org/springframework/data/relational/core/mapping/RelationalMappingContext.html#setForceQuote-boolean-) to `false`.

Alternatively you can create the schema in a consistent way on both databases by quoting the names in your schema creation script.

The first option allows you not to fiddle with the database schema.
But it makes the application depend on avoiding database key words like for example: `ORDER` or `USER`.

The second option is arguably the conceptual cleaner one, because it actually uses the same schema (as far as names are concerned) for both databases, which in itself is certainly valuable. But comes at the cost of quoting names because Postgres doesn't adhere to the behaviour prescribed by the SQL standard of treating unquoted names as uppercase.

Note: There is now an [issue for supporting SpEL expressions for table and column names](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-relational/issues/1325).